# Is there such a thing as a web browser where you specify host and IP for testing new sites?

Tags: browser, dns, hosts-file

Does any Linux software exist where I can specify a host `xyz.com` and an IP. The browser will then request a page from that IP specifying that host, no DNS lookup will be performed. I regularly move sites between servers and need to test the site on a new server before I change the DNS.

I know I can edit my hosts file but it's a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one already, DOH

Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-hosts/aiehidpclglccialeifedhajckcpedom